# Is there any difference in meaning between "pass something" and "pass by something"?

Tags: difference, verbs, phrasal-verbs

Can you please tell me if there as any difference between *pass* something and *pass by* something in the sense of going past it? For example:

> On your way to the grocery store, you are going to **pass** a bank.
>
> On your way to the grocery store, you are going to **pass by** a bank.

I haven't been able to find any difference on the internet and according to dictionaries they mean the same thing. Is it so? If no, what's the nuance of difference?

Comment: On the other hand, there is a difference between "pass the salt" and "pass by the salt" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much difference in your examples, although the latter is said more often in British English. The more common alternative would be "*you will go past a bank*" (or similar). It may also be worth noting that *to pass* something means to excrete it as bodily waste - so you could have an amusing ambiguity if you said something like "*on the way, you will pass water*".

There is a bigger difference in meaning when something passes you, rather than *you* passing *it*. Idiomatically, if something 'passes you by', it means you missed it, didn't notice it, or didn't take full advantage of it - for example, "*that joke passed me by*" means you failed to notice the joke, and "*life passed me by*" means you did not live your life to the full.

Answer (score 0):

In British English, "to pass (something)" usually refers to get an object from yourself to another person, especially in sports. However, "to pass by (something)" is being near something for a short period of time as an effect of your journey.